# Ask the user to unlock the screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, jitsi, android-connectionservice

I am using [react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep).

When the user answer the incoming call and the phone is locked, is it possible to ask the user to unlock his phone in order to open my app ?
Like WhatsApp, when there is a VideoCall, the phone must be unlock to answer the call

Comment: I hope this article can help you to solve this problem. https://blog.theodo.com/2021/03/react-native-incoming-call-ui-callkeep/